# How to calculate the result of a recursive equation?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, math-software, wolfram-alpha, calculator

I'm looking for a tool (like Wolfram Alpha) that can calculate the result of  $ B(P,N) $

Where $B(P,N)$ is a recursive function defined as follows:

## $
\left\{\begin{matrix}
B(P,N)=\frac{-(-1)^{\frac{N}{2^{P-1}}+\sum_{i=1}^{P-1}(\frac{-B(P-i,N)}{2^{i}})}+1}{2}\\ 
P\in \mathbb{N}_{>0}\\ 
N\in \mathbb{N}
\end{matrix}\right.
$

Note that $ \sum_{i=1}^{0}f(x)=0 $ summation is an empty sum, so:

### $$ B(1,N)=\frac{-(-1)^{\frac{N}{2^{1-1}}+\sum_{i=1}^{0}(\frac{-B(0,N)}{2^{i}})}+1}{2}=\frac{-(-1)^{\frac{N}{2^{0}}+0}+1}{2}=\frac{-(-1)^{N}+1}{2} $$

I tried using Wolfram Alpha, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the sum goes from $i=1$ to $i=P-1$, then for $P=1$ is it the empty sum, which equals zero?

Comment: If it's a typo, and the sum starts at $i=0$, then you need to know the initial condition of $B(0,11)$. Otherwise, you can solve directly by substituting in the values for $P$ and $N$.

Comment: @Joe Yes, but i am looking for a software that can calculate the result of the equation by changing the parameters P and N

Comment: You can write a program in some programming language of your choice for this kind of function.

Comment: @Joe It isn't a typo, the sum starts from $ i=1 $ to $ P-1 $, and the initial condition $ B(0,N) $ should never occur because $ \sum_{i=1}^{0}f(x)=0 $ so $ \sum_{i=1}^{0}B(0,N)=0 $

Comment: Oh, so you're not trying to "calculate the result of $B(1,11)$" like it says in your post, but rather calculate the results for arbitrary $P$, $N$? Then I agree with @mvw, use the programming language of your choice, many of which are free. I recommend Python. It wouldn't be harder than typesetting in MathJax. Installing doesn't take long, or you could just use Google Colab https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb  Depending on the values you want to compute, you may need to use memoization.

Comment: Oh, but looks like you will have $-1$ raised to a complex power. I'm not sure how you want to handle that.

Comment: @Joe In which case I'll have −1 raised to a complex power?

Comment: I haven't worked out values by hand, but any fractions in the exponents would turn into complex numbers, or at least would become imaginary exponents, which would become complex numbers. Do you know that the exponents should always be integers for some reason that you have not included in your post?

Comment: @Joe The exponent of my equation is always an integer, in fact the result of $\frac{N}{2^{P-1}}+\sum_{i=1}^{P-1}(\frac{-B(P-i,N)}{2^{i}})$ is always an integer.
This is a formula I wrote to convert a number from base 10 to base 2, in fact, $B(P,N)$ can only give $0$ or $1$ as a result.
For example if you want to calculate bit number 3 of 11 ($11_{10}=1011_{2}$), you can calculate it like this $B(3,11)=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined:
$$ S(P,N) = \sum_{i=1}^P \frac{ B(P-i,N) }{2^i}$$
And rewrote your equations as:
$$B(P,N) = \frac{1 - (-1)_{}^{ \frac{N}{2^{P-1}} - S(P-1,N)}}{2}$$
$$S(P,N) = \frac{B(P,N) + S(P-1,N)}{2}$$
Then I implemented them in Python with the following code:

```
def B(P, N, memo_B=None, memo_S=None, verbose=False):

    if not (type(P) is int and type(N) is int):
        raise ValueError("P and N must be integers")

    if P < 1:
        raise ValueError("P must be at least 1")  

    if memo_B == None:
        memo_B = {}

    if memo_S == None:
        memo_S = {(0,N): int(0)}

    if (P,N) in memo_B:
        return memo_B[(P,N)]

    if (P-1,N) in memo_S:
        sb = memo_S[(P-1,N)]
    else:
        sb = ( B(P-1, N, memo_B, memo_S, verbose=verbose) 
              + S(P-2, N, memo_B, memo_S, verbose=verbose) )
        if sb % 2 == 0:
            sb = int(sb//2)
        else:
            sb = sb/2

    bb = (int(1) - (int(-1))**( N/(2**(P-1)) - sb))

    if bb % 2 == 0:
        bb = int(bb//2)
    else:
        bb = bb/2

    memo_S[(P-1,N)] = sb
    memo_B[(P,N)] = bb

    if verbose:
        print(f"S({P-1},{N}) = {sb}")
        print(f"B({P},{N}) = {bb}")

    return bb


def S(PS, NS, memo_B, memo_S, verbose=False):

    if (PS, NS) in memo_S:

        return memo_S[(PS, NS)]

    else:

        if (PS, NS) in memo_B:
            bs = memo_B[(PS, NS)]
        else:
            bs = B(PS, NS, memo_B, memo_S, verbose=verbose)

        if (PS-1, NS) in memo_S:
            ss = memo_S[(PS-1, NS)]
        else:
            ss = S(PS-1, NS, memo_B, memo_S, verbose=verbose)

        memo_S[(PS-1,NS)] = ss
        memo_B[(PS,NS)] = bs

        if verbose:
            print(f"S({PS-1},{NS}) = {ss}")
            print(f"S({PS},{NS}) = {bs}")

        return ss
```

When I tested it with this:

```
for j in range(11):
    bits = [None]*4
    for i in range(4):
        bits[3-i] = B(i+1,j)
    print(bits)
```

The output was as expected:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help @Joe.

I also found another solution using Wolfram Language
(https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2354584)

```
b[p_Integer,n_Integer]:=(-Power[-1,n/Power[2,p-1]+Sum[-b[p-i,n]/Power[2,i],{i,1,p-1}]]+1)/2

B[l_Integer,n_Integer]:=Sum[b[j,n]*Power[10,j-1],{j,1,l}]

B[8,121]
```

Output:

```
1111101
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Nice. I wonder if Mathematica automatically implements memoization in its recursive functions. Or maybe it's not that important for this problem, I didn't test it, I just typically implement it for any recursive functions